# Cant send text from UITextField using SwiftMailGun

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, mailgun

I'm trying to send some text into the email from `UITextField` but it sends nothing, but when I using textView all working fine. Here is part of code:

```
@IBAction func sendButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let mailgun = MailgunAPI(apiKey: "key-*************",
                             clientDomain: "*********.mailgun.org")

    mailgun.sendEmail(to: "**********@gmail.com", from: self.tema.text!, subject: self.message.text!, bodyHTML: "<b>test<b>") { mailgunResult in

        if mailgunResult.success{
            print("Email was sent")
            print(self.tema.text!)
            print(self.message.text!)
        }

    }
}
```

Here is console output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVoDd.png)

Comment: what do you mean "it sends nothing"? Do you receive empty email or don't you receive anything? Btw. you shouldn't post your real data in the question:)

Comment: It didn't send email. What mean's "real data?"

Comment: hmm, did it crash or throw an exception? I mean your API-Key, Client-Domain and email looks like it's a real data, not just some random strings

Comment: No, all work fine, it just did not send email. When I using textView (textView.text) - it send's me email. But in my case i need to send this from 2 textFields

Comment: example you provided in the question, is it a working one or not? I mean in case above, do you get your email? If so, can you post example, that is not working?

Comment: 1 problem could be, that "from" is not a valid email according to log: "asdas as"

Comment: The example in a question didn't work. That can send any text from UITextView (like asdaa asdasd or something like this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! That was my fail!

```
 @IBAction func sendButton(sender: UIButton) {

    let mailgun = MailgunAPI(apiKey: "key-***************",
                             clientDomain: "sandbox***************.mailgun.org")


    mailgun.sendEmail(to: "mdmabook@gmail.com", from: "Test User <test@test.com>", subject: message.text!, bodyHTML: tema.text!) { mailgunResult in

        if mailgunResult.success{
            print("Email was sent")
            print(self.tema.text!)
            print(self.message.text!)
        }

    }

}
```